# Encrypt and Decrypt data with Meteor and Java

Tags: java, meteor, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have my application's UI built in Meteor and it gets and send the data from REST API (Spring CXF). I would like to encrypt the data in Meteor, and decrypt the same in REST API code. I am using AES for encryption and Decryption. In Meteor i am using https://atmospherejs.com/jparker/crypto-aes package for encryption. I have written the below code in java for decryption the encryption key send by Meteor.

```
    public class AESTest {
           private static String AESStr = "<Encrypted KEY>";
           public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                    Security.addProvider(new    org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
                System.out.println(decrypt(AESStr, "Test"));
           }
        public static String decrypt(String responseStr, String passPhrase) throws        GeneralSecurityException {
             String decryptedStr = "";
             try {
                        Cipher cipher = getCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, passPhrase);
                        byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(responseStr.getBytes());
                        byte[] decryptedWithKey = cipher.doFinal(decoded);
                        byte[] decrypted = Arrays.copyOfRange(decryptedWithKey, 16, decryptedWithKey.length);
                        decryptedStr = new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return decryptedStr;
        }

        private static Cipher getCipher(int mode, String passPhrase) throws Exception {
                SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(passPhrase.getBytes(), "AES");
                byte[] IV = new byte[16];
                new Random().nextBytes(IV);
                AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
                cipher.init(mode, secretKeySpec, paramSpec);
                return cipher;
        }
}
```

When I run the code i am getting below exception

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at com.tph.r3.EncodeTest.decrypt(EncodeTest.java:37)
    at com.tph.r3.EncodeTest.main(EncodeTest.java:26)
```

Can anyone guide me with the issue?

Comment: Does decryption work with with crypto-aes packge ? I mean using CryptoJS.AES.decrypt().

Comment: Yes, It works Perfectly

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the decryption logic w.r.t  IV. You are selecting an IV randomly to initialize decryption cipher which is wrong. You need to use the same IV that was used to encrypt the responseStr which forms its first 16 bytes usually.

In the current form your getCipher() can be used only for encryption where IV is selected randomly but not for decryption. Better write another method.

Psuedocode for decryption:

```
decCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(securityKey , "AES");

//IV + Cipher 
byte [] cipherWithIV = Base64.decodeBase64(responseStr.getBytes()));

//Extract IV
 byte [] iv = new byte [16];
 byte [] cipherWithoutIV = new byte [cipherWithIV.length - 16 ];

//First 16 bytes
for(i < 16; i++) {
    iv [i] = cipherWithIV [i];
}

//Rest of the cipher ie 16 -> cipherWithIV.length
for(i < cipherWithIV.length; i++) {
    cipherWithoutIV [j] = cipherWithIV[i];
    j++;
}

//
IvParameterSpec ivParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

//
decCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivParamSpec);

//Decrypt cipher without IV
decText = decCipher.doFinal(cipherWithoutIV);

//Convert to string
decString = new String(decText,"UTF8");
```